# Calculus Word Problem

Tags: calculus

Sodium chlorate crystals are easy to grow in the shape of cubes by allowing a solution of water and sodium chlorate to evaporate slowly. If $V$ is the volume of such a cube with side length $x$, calculate the derivative when $x = 4 \text{ mm}$.

$$V'(4) = \cdots \text{ mm}^3/\text{mm}$$

I thought that:

$$V'(4) = 64 \text{ mm}^3/\text{mm}$$

Because volume of a cube $=$ $4 \times 4 \times 4$

Comment: In your first equation, what is the "?" supposed to represent? I think if you replace that with the correct derivative of V(x), you'll be able to find your answer. Just to be clear: write the equation for the volume of a cube with side length x, then take the derivative of that equation, then plug in 4.

Comment: an unknown number

Comment: I don't have an equation.

Comment: Try searching the internet or your calculus book for equation for the volume of a cube.

Comment: $x * x * x$ right?

Comment: Can you write x times x times x in a simpler form? What shorthand notation do we have for multiplying something by itself several times?

Comment: Oh I get it $x^3$ and the derivative of that would be $3x^2$

Comment: So the answer would be 48. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 6):

$V(x)=x^3$ is the volume of a cube with side $x$. Take the derivative of that to get $V'(x)$ and then calculate $V'(4)$.